# Formik onSubmit is not working when there is no input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I am trying to make a form with Next.js, typescript and formik + yup libraries.
I have 2 situations. When there is a input and formik gets value and second when input is not visible and button should work as onClick button.

I have to use formik.
When there is no input field handleSubmit does not fires at all.

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { object, SchemaOf, string } from "yup";
import { Button } from "@components/Button";
import { Input } from "@components/Input";

import styles from "./Form.module.scss";
import React from "react";

interface FormValues {
  name: string;
}

const initialValues: FormValues = {
  name: "",
};

export const Form = () => {
  const username = false;

  const validationSchema: SchemaOf<FormValues> = object({
    name: string().min(1).max(30, "maxLengthError").required("requiredError"),
  });

  const handleAlternative = (values) => console.log("Alternative", values);

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values, { resetForm }) => {
      console.log(values);
      handleAlternative(values);
      resetForm();
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} className={styles.form}>
      {username && (
        <Input
          id="name"
          type="name"
          label={"Name"}
          value={formik.values.name}
          error={!!formik.errors.name}
          errorMessage={formik.errors.name}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
      )}
      <div className="justify-center gap-4">
        <Button
          type="submit"
          disabled={!!username && (!formik.isValid || !formik.dirty)}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I have tried to change type='onSubmit' to onClick= but then formik does not work at all.

I am using Next.js, formik, yup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is remove
.required("requiredError") when there is no input.
If you need .required when input is on you can add it like this:

```
  const nameSchema: SchemaOf<FormValues> = object({
    name: string().min(1).max(30, "maxLengthError").required("requiredError"),
  });

  const validationSchema: SchemaOf<FormValues> = username ? nameSchema : object();
```